# Word Prediction Using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I had this question and was wondering if you guys can help me:

A simple implementation of the word suggestion feature relies on creating a data structure that stores information about what words are likely to follow a given word. This data structure is typically created by processing a collection of text documents (a.k.a. a corpus).

Suppose the corpus we are using is a tiny one consisting of the following string:

```py
wordstring = 'it was the best of times it was the worst of times it was the age of wisdom it was the age of foolishness'
```

- Implement a function `get_pair_freq` that computes the frequencies of pairs of consecutive words in a given string (e.g., `wordstring` is taken as the argument). The output of calling `get_pair_freq(wordstring)` should be a dictionary where keys are pairs of words and values are the number of occurrences of each pair. The expected output is:

```py
{('it', 'was'): 4, ('was', 'the'): 4, ('the', 'best'): 1, ('best', 'of'): 1, ('of', 'times'): 2, ('times', 'it'): 2, ('the', 'worst'): 1, ('worst', 'of'): 1, ('the', 'age'): 2, ('age', 'of'): 2, ('of', 'wisdom'): 1, ('wisdom', 'it'): 1, ('of', 'foolishness'): 1}
```

- Process the dictionary above to output a new dictionary that stores information about what words are likely to follow each preceding word. The expected output is

```py
{'it': [('was', 4)], 'was': [('the', 4)], 'the': [('best', 1), ('worst', 1), ('age', 2)], 'best': [('of', 1)], 'of': [('times', 2), ('wisdom', 1), ('foolishness', 1)], 'times': [('it', 2)], 'worst': [('of', 1)], 'age': [('of', 2)], 'wisdom': [('it', 1)]}
```

where the values are each a list of tuples representing how often a word follows the given key.

I've already done the first problem:

```
wordstring = 'it was the best of times it was the worst of times \
it was the age of wisdom it was the age of foolishness'


def get_pair_freq(key):
    wordstring_separated = []
    words = ""

    for x in wordstring:
        if(x != " "):
            words = words + x
        else:
            wordstring_separated.append(words)
            words = ""
    wordstring_separated.append(words)

    pair_list = [(wordstring_separated[i],wordstring_separated[i + 1]) for i in range(len(wordstring_separated) - 1)]

    pair_count = {}    
    for y in pair_list:
        if y not in pair_count:
            pair_count[y] = 1
        else:
            pair_count[y] += 1

    print(pair_count)

get_pair_freq(wordstring)
```

But I'm having trouble with the second problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What kind of trouble have you run in to?

Comment: can you clarify your question? what is the second problem? (I may be being dumb and not reading or...)

Comment: @rpgstar I think the second problem is the second bullet point (Process the dictionary above to output a new dictionary that stores information about what words are likely to follow each preceding word.)

Comment: ah. i see. thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly modifying your code would do the trick -

```
wordstring = 'it was the best of times it was the worst of times \
it was the age of wisdom it was the age of foolishness'

def get_pair_freq(key):
    wordstring_separated = []
    words = ""

    for x in wordstring:
        if(x != " "):
            words = words + x
        else:
            wordstring_separated.append(words)
            words = ""
    wordstring_separated.append(words)

    pair_list = [(wordstring_separated[i],wordstring_separated[i + 1]) for i in range(len(wordstring_separated) - 1)]

    pair_count = {}    
    for y in pair_list:
        if y not in pair_count:
            pair_count[y] = 1
        else:
            pair_count[y] += 1
    return pair_count #Added return statement to get the result dict

t = get_pair_freq(wordstring) # get the dict
list1, list2 = zip(*list(t.keys())) #split dict keys
list3 = t.values() # get dict values in a list 

FinalDict  = dict(zip(list1,zip(list2,list3))) #combine all 3 list and convert to dict
```